# canvas : shape + shadow

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to draw a shape then add shadow but shadow is over the filled color I need it to be under it .. I can't explain the situation well so here is an example on jsfiddle

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(170, 80);
context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
context.bezierCurveTo(430, 40, 370, 30, 340, 50);
context.bezierCurveTo(320, 5, 250, 20, 250, 50);
context.bezierCurveTo(200, 5, 150, 20, 170, 80);
context.closePath();
context.lineWidth = 5;     
context.fillStyle = "#8ED6FF";
context.strokeStyle = "#0000ff";     
context.shadowColor = "#000000";
context.shadowBlur    = 2;
context.shadowOffsetX = 5;
context.shadowOffsetY = 5;
context.fill();     
context.stroke();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j8u8p/ thx

Comment: @DC_ you using an old (or poor) browser?

Comment: Accept some answers @Issam Zoli - you will get better answers if you accept some...

Comment: Nope @Neurofluxation, I get a 404 page. Does it work for you?

Comment: http://jawbfl.blogspot.com/2012/02/canvas-shape-shadow.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/j8u8p/11/

Note: All I did was rearrange the context calls and add in a `globalCompositeOperation`

p.s. this looks nicer: http://jsfiddle.net/j8u8p/13/

p.p.s this is tweaked because you moaned about the gap: http://jsfiddle.net/j8u8p/16/

Comment: Indeedy, it allows basic blending modes - like Photoshop ^_^

Comment: but there is a space between shape and shadow !!

Comment: Just make sure you go back to: `context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";` - that's the default ^_^